# JSON parsing error in perl

Tags: json, perl

I get the error

> EXECUTION FAILED  ...malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)")"

when I parse my JSON string from DB to this snippet.

```
my $json_geno1 = decode_json($geno_set_one);
warn Dumper($json_geno1);
```

Am I missing something ? The json string is from the Database.

```
 $VAR1 = [
   '{"":"No Call","rs1032807":"AG","rs718757":"AG","rs6557634":"CC","rs995553":"CG","rs6166":"AG","rs4925":"AA","rs502843":"GT","rs725029":"No Call","rs3904872":"GG","rs1402695":"TT","rs719601":"AA","rs2374061":"AG","rs952503":"TT","rs1801262":"AG","rs5215":"CT","rs978422":"CC","rs12828016":"GG","rs958388":"AG","rs999072":"CT","rs967344":"AG","rs2207782":"CC","rs349235":"AA","rs1074553":"CT","rs1395936":"AG","GS35220":"CT","rs7627615":"AG","rs727336":"AG","rs2077774":"AC","rs8065080":"CC","rs1131498":"TT","rs2247870":"No Call","rs803172":"TT","rs1541290":"AG","rs1414904":"AA","rs1928045":"No Call","rs2077743":"GT","rs2361128":"No Call","rs3795677":"AG","rs1030687":"CT","rs156318":"GG","rs952768":"CC","rs1363333":"TT","rs7298565":"AG","rs310929":"CC","rs2369898":"CT","rs1327118":"CC","rs4619":"AG","rs965323":"TT","rs2887851":"AG","rs1862456":"GT","rs6759892":"GT","rs753381":"AG","rs1805034":"CC","rs1812642":"AA","rs4075254":"CT","rs1805087":"AA","rs532841":"CT","rs951629":"GG","rs2286963":"GG","rs763553":"CT","rs1074042":"GG","rs2241714":"GG","rs894240":"TT","rs522073":"CT","GS35205":"TC","rs1368136":"TT","rs1426003":"GG","rs2016588":"No Call","rs621277":"No Call","rs727081":"GG","rs1392265":"AC","rs1079820":"No Call","rs4843075":"AG","rs156697":"CC","rs11096957":"AC","rs1952161":"GG","rs1961416":"AG","rs1585676":"GG","rs890910":"TT","rs171953":"AG","rs1843026":"CC","rs1515002":"CC","rs756497":"No Call","rs1293153":"No Call","rs754257":"GT","rs649058":"AG","rs726957":"AG","rs728189":"No Call","GS34251":"TC","rs3742207":"No Call","rs210310":"CT","rs2216629":"AG","rs1541836":"CT","rs722952":"CT","rs1105176":"GG"}'
    ];
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show your JSON data

Answer (score 5):

You should probably use:

```
my $json_geno1 = decode_json($VAR1[0]);
```

because `$VAR1` is now an array.

This JSON is valid (I've tested it in PHP) and I get object from this string without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly same error. Which got resolved by removing for below code

```
my $json;
{
  local $/;
  open ($fh, "+<temp.json") or die $!;
  my $json = <$fh>;
  close $fh;
}
```

and got resolved by removing the my from line number 5.

```
my $json;
{
  local $/;
  open ($fh, "+<temp.json") or die $!;
  $json = <$fh>;
  close $fh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this* msg too, when i tried to call the read function like this:

perl json_read_test.pl /server/lib/Schema/user_data.schema.json

When I used it with ./ or without /  or with full path name, that solved the problem.

**
"malformed JSON string, neither tag, array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at /usr/share/perl5/JSON.pm line 190."

Answer (score -2):

```
my $json_geno1 = decode_json($geno_set_one->[0]);
warn Dumper($json_geno1);
```

Comment: Hey alexandr! Welcome to SO!  Mind adding a bit more "meat" to your answer? we usually don't do code-only answers, as they are not super helpful for future visitors :) a bit of context would be appeciated ^^