# Unable to get good API result searching by SKU

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm trying to look for a product with a specific SKU using this API call

```
/api/v2/products?sku=P99X-GO
```

and I get the error

```
malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)")
```

I've tried putting the sku in single quotes and double quotes, but nothing works. I've tried encoding the hyphen to %2D -- that doesn't help.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request URL and query parameter are correct, although you may want to look into [updating your request to Oauth](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/#migrating-to-oauth) and the [v3 products](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/#/reference/catalog/products) endpoint. However, your request URL is formatted correctly for Basic auth and the v2 products endpoint. :)

It looks like the error is coming from the way your script is handling the JSON response, which will come back as an array. You might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26300663/8521556

If that doesn't point you in the right direction, it would be good to see the code you're using the make the request and handle the response.